# Как сделать рамку QLabel?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Мне нужно сделать рамку для `QLabel` , я сделал ее так:

```
label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
label.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box | QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
```

Выдает вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как подогнать размер рамки к `QLabel`?

Comment: Это и есть рамка вокруг метки, просто метка растянута во все стороны на родителе.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin это я понимаю, ее как то можно подогнать под QLabel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)

        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 120, 
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, 
                                           QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(110, 20, 
                                            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
                                            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Test', self.widget)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(110, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
                                                     QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 119, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, 
                                                     QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)


style = """
QWidget {
    background: #262D37;
}
QLabel {
    background: #ff2D37;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 2px;
    outline: none;
}
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(style)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(370, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно ли это сделать проще в размере кода?

Comment: @Lcashe  не совсем понял ваш уточняющий вопрос. Вы спросили: `Как сделать рамку QLabel?`, я вам показал один из вариантов. Возможны ли другие варианты - да, возможны. Если у вас какие-то трудности с вашим реальным примером, то задайте новый вопрос. Опишите что вы хотите сделать, что у вас не получается и приложите минимально-ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ пример, который демонстрирует проблему.